# Can't delete a collection of Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

I am retrieving a collection from db and want to delete it. This is the code.

```
 $signal_id = $request->del_signal_id;
    $signal_details = VwDistressSignals::where('signal_id', $signal_id)->delete();
    return "Success";
}
```

And this is the error.

```
message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1395 Can not delete from join view 'dvp.vw_distresssignals' (SQL: delete from `vw_distresssignals` where `signal_id` = 2)"
```

I have also tried giving all the column names. This is the model...

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Reliese\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class VwDistressSignals extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'vw_distresssignals';
}
```

Comment: Show us the `VwDistressSignals` model

Comment: I have edited the question and edited the model.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because your relationship is not properly defined.

Comment: yeah I think thats so silly of me I was using the wrong model. But how come I was getting the right data from the collection, Is it because of some relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Delete with the loop

```
$signal_id = $request->del_signal_id;
$signal_details = VwDistressSignals::where('signal_id', $signal_id)->get();

foreach($signal_details as $detail) 
{
  $detail->delete();
}

return "Success";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared your model, I assume it corresponds to a database view rather than a table.

If so try deleting from the base table(s) as join views are not deletable.

> DELETE ... Join views are not allowed.
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html